# How can I reload a single activity with new data each time the activity is started?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a list view with over 100 items. Each of these items show description when clicked on them. The problem is that I don't want over a hundred activities to display the description of each item instead I want to implement a single activity which refreshes the whole view and sets it to the new data depending upon the item clicked.How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i=new Intent(yourActivity.this,next.class);


    String  s = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);   
     //query the database for the row with this string.. and get the necessary information

    i.putExtra("name",s1);
    i.putExtra("id",s2);
    startActivity(i);



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new activity that only displays the details of your selected item. This activity is created for each item but you would open it, press the back button open it again with different content. Have a look at Intent and their extras as how to pass the data to your details activity.

Comment: I didn't get you.Can u elaborate?

Comment: @DineshVenkata Intents are used to navigate between activities. You'll want to have a 'DetailActivity', and send it some startup data via an Intent. Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html